# JavaScript How does local scope variable is remains stored on function return

Tags: javascript, function, return

As topic title says, i don't understand how its work. So here is my simple example:

```
function bar () {
    var a = 0;
    return {
        baz: function () {
            console.log(a++);
        }
    }
}
var foo = bar();
foo.baz() // 0
foo.baz() // 1
foo.baz() // 2
```

i thought that when i used "bar" function, it should to return me this object

```
{
    baz: function () {
        console.log(0++);
    }
}
```

with replaced variable in it and all local variables should be deleted after execution, but no! variable "a" is saved and can be used, so i don't get it. Can someone explain me this, please

Comment: Variables don't go away as long as they're still referenced from somewhere, even if their containing function returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read up on **JavaScript closures**:

> Closures are functions that refer to independent (free) variables
>   (variables that are used locally, but defined in an enclosing scope).
>   In other words, these functions 'remember' the environment in which
>   they were created.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

That will help you understand this better and is really pretty important for every JS developer.

Comment: Worth noting that every function in JS is technically a closure.